# take view of unbounded iota is not a sized range

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following code

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  auto int_view = std::views::iota(0, 20) | std::views::take(15);
  std::cout << int_view.size() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine and prints `15` as the size of `int_view`. However if we make the iota unbounded like `iota(0)` instead of `iota(0,20)`, then that code won't compile because `std::ranges::take_view<_Vp>::size()` requires a `sized_range`, which the unbounded iota is clearly not. My question is why does it require a sized range? once we take a number of elements the corresponding view should be able to know it's size in constant time.

Answer (score 4):

`views::take` only guarantees an upper bound on the size of the range, not its exact size which is what `.size()` must return.

C++ ranges/views are either bounded (have `.size()` and satisfy `std::ranges::sized_range`) or unbounded, there is no finer distinction for infinite ranges or minimum-/maximum-guaranteed lengths.

`iota(0)` returns an unbounded range, `views::take` therefore has no idea how many elements there are, could be zero or could be infinite for all it knows, and so the `take` must be of unknown size - unbounded.

Comment: Note that just because a range is non-sized does not mean that it is "unbounded". An unbounded range is one where the iterators will never be equal to any sentinel value. An unsized range may be one where there is a size, but computing it is a linear-time operation.

Comment: This comment, specially the last statement, actually clarifies the situation more than the answer: I can see how take can know the size as there must be one, but can not be known in constant time